# What was the reasoning behind the lack of a right click in the Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

On *nix and OS X, windowed terminals support ctrl+v/ctrl+shift+v/cmd+v for paste, and right click past/copy.

On windows however you need to right click the title bar and go into an edit sub menu. Despite progress on other Operating systems, and Windows applications that try to fix this, Microsoft has not changed this.

Given that when the command line windowed app was introduced into Windows there were already contextual menus and keyboard shortcuts, why did neither of these make it into cmd.exe? Is there a functional reason it can't be done?

Comment: Because Microsoft wanted to handle it differently.  Furthermore the command shell has changed slightly, what you describe, wasn't always the case.

Comment: Probably because it's ancient, compared to the modern terminals of other OS...

Comment: There is no reason that it can't be done. There also isn't a great deal of a reason to do it. Set the quick edit mode then you won't have to go into a menu every time you want to copy and paste.

Comment: Further to what @EBGreen said, I use QuickEdit mode on all command shells. It's as easy as normal Windows right-click, but works slightly differently: hold left-click and move mouse to select, then right-click to copy and a second right-click to paste at the cursor. The selection is also different, in that you can select a block in the middle of the screen and it won't include the starts of lines, unlike in normal windows. It uses the same clip-board, so copy and paste can be shared with normal windows.

Comment: I'm aware of 3rd party applications, the question is what was Microsofts reasoning/rationale for not doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider how things were when Windows 95 was new.

Back then, you could run full-screen DOS apps in a Windows 95 command window - it wasn't NT's `cmd.exe` but `command.com`.  Many DOS programs (like `EDIT.COM`) supported the mouse in text mode.  So mouse movements and click in the window need to be passed to the underlying DOS (or `ntvdm` under NT versions of Windows).

But if you want to do something to the actual text in the window, then you need to call up the context menu.  It's also why the "Mark" option lets you draw a box to capture text rather than operating on full lines like a terminal.

Now, on `cmd.exe`, you can right click the window to get to "Edit..."  It's been forever since I've used a 9x version of Windows but I do believe the way you were supposed to get to that "Edit..." menu was by right clicking the title bar and right clicking the screen didn't work.  I could be wrong about that.

Even though in 64-bit versions there is no longer an `ntvdm` emulating DOS, `cmd.exe` hasn't really been updated to match.

Answer (score 1):

The CMD is just an old application at the time of its initial inception the option to right click was not needed. CMD is more like a legacy application to get to a dos prompt.  Windows now has the `Power Shell` which does support the right click options as well as many new improvements that you are use to on other OS terminals(such as bash, etc.)